# SVG polygon animate starts with some delay, when I want it as quick as CSS keyframes EDIT: slowdown caused by scripts

Tags: html, css, svg, polygon, svg-animate

I'm loading the site with a timer similar to below but am confused as to why it loads statically then only after a second or so it'll start rotating. By that time the site usually loads, so would rather it be seen to be doing something even when the user glimpses it for a fraction of a second, as they would with CSS keyframes initiated rotation.

```html
<svg class="tri" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
     <polygon points="27.6,11.5 94.8,50 27.6,88.5" 
            style="fill:none;stroke:#444;stroke-width:4">
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" dur="5"
       type="rotate"
       from="0 50 50"
       to="360 50 50" 
       repeatCount="indefinite"
      />
     </polygon>
    </svg>
```

I'm using SVG SMIL animation because I'm also morphing a shape and the only way to synchronise with the rotation was to make all the polygons SMIL animated.

EDIT: Indeed, on its own and without any scripts (that include an Ajax call?), the animation starts immediately. However, unlike with keyframes, Javascript scripts are causing a delay in its start. Is this normal behaviour? Is there a way to circumvent it?

Comment: in your example the triangle start rotate immediately

Comment: You're right, did a basic test. I've edited the post to reflect what seems to be the issue - javascript, if not more specifically an Ajax call...

Comment: what the javascript do with the svg? if there is the problem, you should share it before anything else..

Comment: Absolutely nothing, the svg is loaded before anything else, and even if I call the script (Ajax call) at the end the animation still gets interrupted

Comment: if the js not related to the svg, it should not effect. find a way to reproduce the problem, for other will able to help